# can't remove "GRANT USAGE"

Tags: mysql, permissions

I was testing some stuff, and added a:

```
grant usage on statistics.* to cptnotsoawesome@localhost identified by 'password';
```

so now when I do

```
show grants for cptnotsoawesome@localhost;
```

I can see that one of them is:

```
Grants for cptnotsoawesome@localhost
----------------------------------
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'cptnotsoawesome'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'somePEW-PEWstring'
```

Now I want to remove it as I think it's a security hazard, so i do the:

```
REVOKE USAGE ON *.* FROM 'cptnotsoawesome'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

But it still shows that USAGE grant in the grant list.

```
Grants for cptnotsoawesome@localhost
----------------------------------
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'cptnotsoawesome'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'somePEW-PEWstring'
```

Any ideas why? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Under the hood, when you see a user with USAGE only, that the user is written in the mysql.user table with all global privileges turned off.

You originally stated the the user had this:

```
grant usage on statistics.* to cptnotsoawesome@localhost identified by 'password';
```

You should see a row in `mysql.user` with the MD5 password and all globals privs set to `N`. You should also see a row in mysql.db with

- user='cptnotsoawesome'
- host='localhost'
- db='statistics'
- all DB levels privs set to 'Y'

You should be able to see them with this query

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.db
WHERE user='cptnotsoawesome'
AND host='localhost'
AND db='statistics'\G
```

When you ran the REVOKE command, you simply removed the row from `mysql.db`. This did not touch the row in `mysql.user`. Thus, you could still login to mysql and only have the privs to run

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;
```

If there is a test database called `test` or a database whose first 5 characters are `test_`, (look for it using `SELECT * FROM mysql.db WHERE db LIKE 'test%';`) then the user with just USAGE can have full rights to the test databases. [I wrote about this in ServerFault Sep 2011](https://serverfault.com/a/316554/69271).

If you want to remove the row from mysql.user you could either run

```
DROP USER cptnotsoawesome@localhost;
```

or

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE
WHERE user='cptnotsoawesome'
AND host='localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 11):

**USAGE**   means that user doesn't have any privileges.

```
You have to use 'DROP USER'.
```

`drop user cptnotsoawesome@localhost;`

You can't actually revoke USAGE, without dropping the user.USAGE is a global level privilege.

have a look at [This Link](http://www.mail-archive.com/mysql@lists.mysql.com/msg117043.html).

Comment: I would do it, if that was doing anything wrong to the database, like if it is security threat or something like that, otherwise - i may just leave it

Answer (score 2):

Please look at this question:-

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126225/why-is-a-grant-usage-created-the-first-time-i-grant-a-user-privileges

Basically the USAGE privilege acts like a system level privilege which you can't remove. It's used internally by MySQL so you can manipulate the privilege system.

Comment: So it is not some security threat after all ?